# How to avoid zoom(pinch) from triggering swipeToRefresh layout

Tags: android, pinchzoom, pull-to-refresh

My activity contains webView and SwipeRefresh layout.
if I click to view an image in full screen when I'm zooming out the refresh icon appears and it reloads the webview

There are any suggestions for fixing this bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can make listener when you zoom a image and then make visibility for `SwipeRefreshLayout` hide or gone

```
binding.image.setOn[PinchMethod] {
   binding.swipeRefreshLayout.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Or you can disable SwipeRefreshLayout on there.

Comment: I can 't understand your solution, how can I know if image is shown in full screen mode in WEBVIEW element?

Comment: @BarelElbaz just add container for webview and then make listener on their ID